# Trying to read binary file header from SEGY (seismic data). Does not yield correct integers

Tags: java, binary

SEGY file format is a standard format to store seismic data. It has a 3600 byte header out of which first 3200 is textual header and the rest 400 bytes are binary headers.

I want to read integers from this .sgy file that have important information I need. For example I want to read byte number 3217-3218 to retrieve the sample rate i.e these particular 2 bytes are allotted for sample rate.

Similarly bytes 3221-3222 to read "Number of Samples".  I have the following code. It does not yield the proper integers.

This program should show following results file len as 993204,sample rate as 2 and no of samples as 501 instead it prints file len as 993204,Sample Rate as 53248 and 
No Of Samples as 62720

```
File file = new File("C:\\mysample.sgy");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];    
System.out.println("file len="+file.length());
try
{
//convert file into array of bytes
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
fileInputStream.read(bFile);
fileInputStream.close();
int sampleRate = (((bFile[3217] & 0xff )<<8)|(bFile[3218] & 0xff));          
System.out.println("Sample Rate="+sampleRate);
int noOfSamples = (((bFile[3221] & 0xff )<<8)|(bFile[3222] & 0xff));             
System.out.println("No Of Samples="+noOfSamples);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please help. Am I not reading the binary file correctly?

Comment: The problem (probably) is in the SEGY format. That values themselves are saved as `float 4 ibm` floating point numbers. This essentially means that when you're reading in bytes, you have to be very careful about the [ordering of your bytes on file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture) and in memory.

Comment: Also, I believe you're off by a byte. [According to the definition of SEGY binary headers](http://www.freeusp.org/DDS/users/formats/segy/binhdr.html): your variable `sampleRate` is saved in `segy short` format (also described separately in the link) at offset 3218/3219, and your `nSamples` in `segy short` format at offset 3220/3221.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! According to http://www.seg.org/documents/10161/77915/seg_y_rev1.pdf  3217-3218 = sample interval . and I was reading the exact same bytes, but I should have read 3216-3217 since thats where they are stored in the java array! Its working now! \

Comment: Have you tried reading them with Obspy library in python? it is much better and easier.